# Can you explain this member function template?

Tags: c++

Any one help me by explaining the real use of function templates. How to they work? This morning I saw some code but i still don't understand the real use of this:

```
class A
{
template<class T> T getData() const
{
   const T* pointer == dynamic_cast<const T*>(mData)
   if(0 == pointer)
    {
     T defaultValue = T()
    }
  }
private:
  LData *mData; 
};
```

I don't understand anything of this. Can anyone give me a general idea about function templates?

Thanks

Comment: @user: This code does nothing useful. Where did you find it?

Comment: Find better examples to learn from.  This code is missing `return` statements and semicolons, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I think the should be something like this:

```
class A
{
template<class T> 
T getData() const
{
   const T* pointer = dynamic_cast<const T*>(mData);
   if(0 == pointer) 
     return T();

   return *T;
}
private:
  LData *mData; 
};
```

It's trying to get the mData converting that buffer or class (I don't know what LData is) in a T type.

Comment: While we are already fixing code based on speculation, that first `==` comparison almost certainly was supposed to be a `=` assignment.

Comment: and you need a semi at the end of the cast line